# upgrading Ajax Control Toolkit 3.0.20820

Tags: upgrade, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to upgrade my ajaxcontroltoolkit dll version - 3.0.20820 with the latest version 16.1

Below are couple of controls/class, for which I am facing issue:

1. CollapsiblePanelExtender: property used: CollapsedCssClass & ExpandedCssClass
2. PasswordStrength: property used: Strength
3. CalendarExtender: property used: CalendarMode & Enum - CalendarModeType

Q. What can we use instead of above properties as they are not available in version - 16.1?

Comment: I checked ACT v3.0.20820 and did not find any property you mentioned. Can you please add a link to that release?  https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: Thread related to the same issue -https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/278